# Question about proof of unique solution of differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Theorem:

> Let $a' > 0$, $b > 0$, $(x_0, y_0) \in \Bbb R^2$, $\Bbb R' = \{(x, y) : |x - x_0| < a', |y - y_0| < b\}$, $g: \Bbb R' \to \Bbb R$ continuous on $\Bbb R'$, and for some $k > 0$, $|g(x, y_1) - g(x, y_2)| \leq k |y_1 - y_2|$ for all $(x, y_1)$ and $(x, y_2) \in \Bbb R'$.
>
> Then there exists an $a$ with $0 < a < a'$ and a function $f: [x_0 -a, x_0 + a]$ such that $f$ is the unique solution of the differential equation $y' = g(x,y)$ defined on $[x_0 -a, x_0 + a]$ with $f(x_0) = y_0$.

The proof begins as follows:

> Choose $a$ such that $ak < 1$ and $aM \leq b$ where $M = \max\{|g(x,y)| : (x, y) \in \Bbb R'\}$.

What I don't understand is why it is possible to choose such an $a$. Why does $ak <1$ necessarily mean that $aM \leq b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ak < 1$ does not necessarily mean that $aM \le b$. You just choose an $a$ that fulfills both. For example 
$$ a := \min \left\{ \frac 1{2k}, \frac b{M+1} \right\} $$
Then 
$$ ak \le \frac 1{2k} \cdot k = \frac 12 < 1 $$
and 
$$ aM \le \frac b{M+1} \cdot M \le b. $$